# Make the "must be accompanied by code" warning more direct

Tags: feature-request, questions, jsfiddle

Right now, if you try to post a jsFiddle link without posting code, the site says this:

> Links to jsfiddle.net must be accompanied by code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon.

Sadly, we get people just marking up the link as code to work around it:

[image]

When this happens, the better part of me wonders if the OP simply didn't understand. *(The other part of me has a more harsh opinion, but I strive for my better self.)*

Particularly for the many for whom English is not a native language, if you turn your head sideways and skim, you *could* read the message as telling the user to mark up the link with CTRL+K.

I suggest making the message more direct, opening with a clear statement that code must go in the question:

> The code for your question must be **in the question**, not just linked. Copy the code from jsfiddle.net into your question, and mark it as code by selecting it and using the code toolbar button (`{}`) or pressing Ctrl+K. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon.

And as there's a similar rule for answers, the same thing with "question" => "answer" in that case. (I would not try to have a generic message for both using "post" or similar — again because of English as a second/third/fourth language. I would be as specific as possible, using separate messages for questions and answers. Easy enough to swap in the right word when showing it.)

Related: [*Broaden the jsFiddle (et. al.) filter to disallow links as the only code*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/293783/broaden-the-jsfiddle-et-al-filter-to-disallow-links-as-the-only-code)

Comment: ...or use Ctrl + M and prepare a runnable code snippet.

Comment: How am I discovering Ctrl+K only now ? So much time wasted :(

Comment: @TLama: I wanted to mention Stack Snippets, but was worried about being too verbose and/or setting the bar too high. Stack Snippets aren't where they need to be [and don't seem to be getting any development love](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/239706/134069)...

Comment: How about something like "Links to jsfiddle.net must include some code in the question. Please copy the most relevant sections into a code block (using Ctrl+K to indent)."?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Every now and then in these cases I've left a comment: "Did you see the warning?". The answer is usually something what your "other part" would expect ; ).

Comment: @GuillaumeAlgis Prepare your code snippets in a usable code editor, such as vi or notepad++ or sed or pico or VS.  Then (in vi) `:s/^/    /` will indent everything by 4 spaces, after you have done stuff like convert tabs to spaces and the like.  Any code editor worth its salt can mass-indent, and I don't consider the stack overflow box a good code editor, so ...

Comment: @Yakk Yeah, I usually copy the code into Sublime Text to indent, and then copy back in SO. Still, Ctrl+K is faster :)

Comment: [I hereby apologize](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253459/links-to-jsfiddle-net-must-be-accompanied-by-code-should-tell-the-user-exactl) for this unforeseen consequence. Sometimes I do wonder if implementing my suggestion was helpful to *anyone* at all...

Comment: @BoltClock: Absolutely useful. :-) Improvement is frequently incremental, so this is just building on your previous work.

Comment: I suppose that's one way to look at it optimistically :)

Comment: Looking at this I noticed that there is markdown help is still out of alignment. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/277203/1947286

Comment: The people who didn't read the text that was already there probably won't read the additional, sterner text, because [people don't read](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/uibook/chapters/fog0000000062.html).

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: Absolutely -- I was going to say that somewhere, but decided the question was long enough. People do read enough to know what's stopping them from continuing, however. That's why the first sentence of the change is a direct and clear statement about the policy. If they read more than the first ten words, bonus. :-)

Comment: Hah... http://stackoverflow.com/q/30176365/621962

Comment: What if someone want to link the log? It is funny to enter several hundreds of log lines in the question. In the same time, it is not good to reduce the logs only to look "nice" within the stackoverflow.

Answer (score 16):

As someone who mainly answers HTML, CSS and JavaScript questions I see this behaviour an awful lot. I'd say every 40 or 50 questions I visit contain a question like this which bypasses the JSFiddle link error by placing the link within a code block.

I don't know if what I do is frowned upon, but I personally deal with posts like this by:

1. Commenting out their JSFiddle link:

   ```
   <!-- http://jsfiddle.net/... -->
   ```
2. Leaving a comment on the question stating that this is what I've done and expressing why I've done it:

   > Placing JSFiddle links within a code block to get around the *JSFiddle links must be accompanied by code* error notice is bad and you should feel bad. I've taken the liberty to comment out the link you posted. Please post the relevant code within the question itself, otherwise this question will be closed. Please refer to point 1 within [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
3. Voting to close the question as Off Topic -> "Why Isn't this Code Working?".
4. Down voting the question if it's unsalvageable without the JSFiddle link present.

This often does encourage users to add the appropriate code to their question. Sometimes they do respond by instead leaving a comment on their question with nothing more than the same JSFiddle link, but when this happens their question is often closed pretty swiftly.

If I see that a user has then amended their post I retract my close vote (and remove my down vote if the question's quality has improved) and delete my comment.

There is also the situation where users answer these questions fairly swiftly. I imagine these users are also not aware that this error notice exists and probably aren't aware that the person who asked the question has done anything wrong.

One thing I will add though is that I've noticed that users only tend to do this the once, as questions like this almost always attract multiple down votes (often more down votes than close votes, too).

Comment: I've also noticed that the users who answer this in spite of the blatant disregard of the restriction tend to disregard it themselves in their answers. More downvotes for the rest of us.

Comment: *"... is bad and you should feel bad"* is kind of rude, particularly when the wording of the notice could be misinterpreted (as noted in the OP).

Answer (score 9):

I'm in favor of the suggested edit from T.J. Crowder.

> The code for your question must be **in the question**, not just linked.
>   Copy the code from jsfiddle.net into your question, and mark it as
>   code by selecting it and using the code toolbar button ({}) or
>   pressing Ctrl+K. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon.

That being said, some may still read the same paragraph as:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit **in the question**, consectetur adipiscing elit, copy
>   do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
>   minim veniam, quis nostrud button. Ctrl+K Duis aute irure dolor in
>   reprehenderit in [?] help voluptate.

If the suggested edit doesn't make enough of a dent on people's behavior, we could show an animated gif, or a silent short 5-seconds looped video, of someone cut and pasting code from jsfiddle to StackOverflow.

To make the video sequence more interesting, we could even use a [shortcut key displayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3529329/how-to-display-pressed-keyboard-shortcuts-on-screen-during-presentations-or-scre), and show the shortcuts Ctrl-Tab => Ctrl-A => Ctrl-X => Ctrl-Tab => Ctrl-V => Ctrl-K overlaid one-by-one on the video sequence of screenshots.

Comment: *"If the suggested edit doesn't make enough of a dent on people's behavior, we could show an animated gif, or a silent short 5-seconds looped video, of someone cut and pasting code from jsfiddle to StackOverflow."* LOL!

Comment: Built-in Let Me Snippet That For You animation? +1 do want! Double +1 for accurate reproduction of typical asker's reading capacity.

Answer (score -10):

I think this is a usability problem and changing the message does not help to solve it.

[Aren't the runnable snippets one can add to a post pretty much the same as a jsfiddle?](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) Yes, one is external, one internal, but the provided functionality is kind of the same.

Instead of telling people "Don't link to a website that does something *very similar* to what you can do here" or trying to improve that message in any way, I wonder:

**Why can't SO simply go to that jsfiddle url, fiddle around with what it finds there so that it is an SOfiddle (aka runnable snippet) and replace the link with that.**

We do this with images already. Given a url, SO goes there, loads the image and adds it to the post. I suggest we do the same with the jsfiddles automatically if somebody posts a link to them.

If we are conscerned with the possibility that the code is not executable, we could still take the code from the site. As said above: jsut like we do it with images.

Comment: We're going to do that with every single site like that?  jsbin, codepen, sassmeister, plunkr, etc.  Many of those sites offer the ability to compile languages that do not work in a snippet (Sass, CoffeeScript, Haml, etc.).  It's not just those kinds of sites that are a problem, either.  We have people linking to pastebin, github's gist, drop box, etc.

Comment: I think that's a *different* suggestion and justifies its own feature request, rather than being an answer to this one. That's significant dev even just for jsFiddle, not to mention all the others, and has significant community relations ramifications, and potential pissing-off-jsFiddle/CodePen/etc. ramifications. Then there's the ongoing maintenance even once it's been written once; small changes at the other end blow up the import. So again, a separate topic, not a solution to the simple problem I'm trying to solve here. If and when SE does that work, we can adjust the message to offer it.

Comment: @cimmanon ideally yes. We have a specialised behaviour already, because the website is part of the message. Loading the code from that resource is a more involved process, going a few steps further, but in the same direction. Most importantly, the human causing the issues described in this question is not involved any more. We can solve this problem, or avoid it altogether, at least for common sites. Code not working in snippets is a valid concern, which I addressed in an edit. Please take a look.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I don't think that the significance of dev required to do this makes this less of an answer. I think it's easier to maintain some calls to  APIs/services than to maintain all those incoming questions. There are no ramifications, because this is why websites have APIs: to access their services programmatically.

Comment: Well, I maintain that yes, it's a different issue. It may or may not be complementary, but it's different. If you want to request it, please do a feature request for it.

Comment: JSFiddle has many other features, such as the ability to use SASS or LESS for CSS, along with many different settings for the fiddle (where to load, libs, etc). Not to mention it's not the only service providing such features.

Comment: *"Why can't SO simply go to that jsfiddle url, fiddle around with what it finds there so that it is an SOfiddle (aka runnable snippet) and replace the link with that."* For a start, code posted to JSFiddle is not automatically released under a Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike license, so including a link to JSFiddle in a question does not grant Stack Overflow permission to reproduce its contents. This way lies lawsuits.