# Make code block required if Fiddle link is in question?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

[Referencing this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31116383/why-is-this-not-returning-on-jsfiddle#comment50246202_31116383)

Can it be added that if a user places a Fiddle link, they must add relevant code? There are occasions, such as this question, where the user just drops a Fiddle link and says "The problem is in there somewhere" or "It's in line xx".

I also thought [code was required with Fiddles](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/293510/make-the-must-be-accompanied-by-code-warning-more-direct), but I've seen a few questions come across like this. It was just an idea.

Comment: The requirement isn't being triggered because the link to the fiddle isn't an actual link, just text.

Comment: That users worked around the requirements by breaking his fiddle link... It's impossible to catch all cases. In this case, I'd just downvote, closevote as _"Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**")"_ and move on.

Comment: Or better yet, close as _"Simple typographical error"_. (`<imgsrc` --> `<img src` and `height:35px;.` --> `height:35px;`)

Comment: Got it. Have voted to close.

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, this is already [implemented](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149890/prevent-posts-with-links-to-jsfiddle-and-no-code) and has been for several years.  The problem with this question was that the user bypassed the requirement by not making that a link, it was pure text.

Comment: Why is the post you link to on MSE instead of MSO...? That really seems like a feature that would be specific to SO...

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare The post I linked to was prior to the [MSE-MSO split](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228888/operation-split-all-the-metas-shall-commence-on-april-16-2014).

Comment: I thought during the MSE-MSO split we intelligently chose what to put on each site? It seems odd that that post would go to MSE instead of MSO.

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare During the split things stayed on MSE unless it was completely necessary to move it to MSO