# Fiddle and code snippets

Tags: feature-request, bug

I have tried to edit some questions, [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56647436/using-jquery-to-trigger-css-shake-animation-works-every-other-time-why), that would take great benefit in readability by having a snippet instead of just some plain code.

The edit failed because OP put also a link to an external fiddle and, as stated [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298111/make-code-block-required-if-fiddle-link-is-in-question), links to fiddle requires code.

Wouldn't it be usefull to extend that constrain to "code or snippet"? Is there any reason why this was not implemented before?

Comment: Couldn't you just inline the fiddle as a snippet too?

Comment: @JamesCoyle https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/344484/pasting-fiddle-snippet-into-original-question-as-an-edit/344512#344512

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's actually a [bug], Snippets already do count as code in this check.

What happens here is that to create the snippet, you probably did cut the original code-block.
Then before or when the snippet-editor was open, the check for jsfiddle got triggered.

And the problem: saving the snippet won't make the check run again.
So you end up having the flag still raised and nothing that will make the check run again to lower it down.

The easy workaround is to cut the link to the jsfiddle, wait that the check is done again, and then past again the link to the fiddle.