# Broaden the jsFiddle (et. al.) filter to disallow links as the only code

Tags: feature-request, questions, jsfiddle

Following on from [this feature request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/293510/make-the-must-be-accompanied-by-code-warning-more-direct), the workaround (or misunderstanding) the users are using to get around the "Links to jsFiddle must include code" filter is **trival** to detect *(can you tell I ran into more of them today [just like every day]?)*:

[image]

So: Let's detect them: If the only code in the question is a single line containing nothing but a link to jsFiddle (et. al), it is **not code** and shouldn't exempt the question/answer from the fiddle filter. By "nothing but a link" I mean "parses as a URL to one of the forbidden sites, either on its own or if you stick `http://`/`https://` in front of it."

*Can* they still work around it? Sure:

```
console.log("Please see my fiddle: jsfiddle.net/balderdash
```

But you never know, might prevent *some* of these and make people actually read the darned message. :-)

Comment: I am going to have nightmares from the unclosed paren and quotes

Comment: `@jakekimds: "); // Fixed it for you! Just in time for bed.`

Comment: At this rate we might as well just let users post questions with bare fiddle links, and rather than reject them, post them closed. There are heuristics in place to detect code blocks, so it's only a matter of inverting them and closing any and all fiddle questions that don't appear to have anything that *resembles* code within them - which includes code blocks that contain only or little more than URLs, I'm sure. The console.log example could be a false positive or negative, but if you have a question where the only pertinent code is a single line chances are you don't need a fiddle at all.

Comment: I think there is no reason for a code block to contain the word "jsfiddle" at all. I think a heuristic based on that can be implemented isn't it?
Also why don't block the whole thing altogether and promote Stack Snippets instead?

Comment: Apparently [this has come up before](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/275411/157247). Perhaps we'll get some traction this time.

Comment: TRWTF is that that question is not tagged [tag:javascript] *sigh*

Comment: @BoltClock: That's ...... huh that's a _really_ good idea!

Comment: Would it be possible to grab the content from jsfiddle and display it in the post?

Comment: @AndrewBreksa: Anything's *possible*. :-) But see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/293542/157247 and the comments on it.

Comment: I'm for an "idiot badge" that is awarded if you link to a jsfiddle in a code block...

Comment: Attacking this from a different direction, what about an option to "import code from jsFiddle"? Sure it makes it easier for the question askers to be lazy, but it cuts out "the source of the frustration" entirely. (maybe run the code through a tidy filter on import so I can stop improving the formatting of 90% of the questions I look at? With a line to remove the padded spaces at the beginning of the first line so it tidy's properly)

Comment: @humble.rumble.6x3 That means that _all_ the code get's dumped into the question instead of the relevant bits. That can be pretty annoying.

Comment: Yes, I can see where that could be annoying, but at that point I think I would rather tell the user to slim the code down to relevant code, than to tell the user to include some code at all. Lesser of two evils

Comment: @humble.rumble.6x3: That's a lot of work, see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/293542/157247 and the comments on it.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I didn't realize that it wouldn't just apply to jsFiddle. That would be a lot of work

Answer (score 39):

Yes please.

More often than not when I see links to jsFiddle formatted as code I find myself questioning whether it was a simple mistake by someone who didn't know any better or if it was a deliberate workaround. This should clear that up pretty well.

Adding some more guidance may prevent good faith users from working around the filter and it will make bad faith users easier to identify.

Answer (score -30):

The reason someone will put a link as a code is that the system prevented him from adding the link in the first place.

I think applying your suggestion will only make people think of new workarounds. It is not possible to change people, just keep editing things.

Comment: We understand *why* users are doing this, that's pretty much the source of the frustration; as for the consequences of applying the feature-request? Fair enough, but your answer sounds like you're arguing that we should do nothing to curb mistaken (or 'bad') behaviour, because any action will be met with workarounds and avoidance; so why bother? Which I have to disagree with, since the inevitable conclusion of that path would be "let's never do anything any more."

Comment: @DavidThomas  my suggestion was to keep moderating such behavior because I believe that putting more restrictions will make things even worse.

Comment: When you leave a comment explaining that it is not ok to circumvent the filter, the user will usually comply and paste the relevant code.  However, I have also seen users that will just turn random text into code as well.

Comment: I agree with _in general_, but that's no reason not to do the best we can. It can certainly be taken to absurd extremes, though, usually in cases where the case for disallowing such things was suspect in the first place (e.g. +1/-1 filter in comments)